# Unique Identifier for cell phone, tablet and laptop

Tags: java, c#, unique, coldfusion-9, uniqueidentifier

I am working on application (web based) which needs to track devices (cell phone/tablet/laptop) that have accessed my application (web based). Cookies is not a solution for me as they can be deleted. I found out that uuid identifier can be used. I want to retrieve device manufacturer’s UUID. I am not looking to create a new UUID. Can someone please help me how can I retrieve device manufacturer's UUID using Coldfusion or JAVA or C# or Javascript/jQuery (either one of these language).

Comment: What research you have done so far for this? Did you try implementing any of suggested approached? What issue you are facing in that?

Comment: Have went through few options. Mac address was best for me as It is easy to retrieve. But concern is that It can be spoofed and some devices also change it too. 


Then another option is to use UUID, I found example to get device id using TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() but it is just limited to mobile devices like cell phone.

Comment: Did you research around how do you get the UUID of the device which is making request to your web application in your web application code?

Comment: I have looked into almost all options e.g. fingerprint, cpu id, mac address but nothing seems to work quite well. will appreciate if you can guide me in right direction

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. Without a more detailed explanation, as of your development environment, it gets a bit difficult to answer.
Here are a awnser from Anthony Forloney, to do this in Java on https://stackoverflow.com/a/2785493/7970301

[`Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID) returns the Android ID as an *[unique for each user](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID)* 64-bit hex string.

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                        Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

If you work with Ionic, this is another option:

```
import { UniqueDeviceID } from '@ionic-native/unique-device-id';
constructor(private uniqueDeviceID: UniqueDeviceID) { }
...
this.uniqueDeviceID.get()
.then((uuid: any) => console.log(uuid))
.catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/unique-device-id/

Comment: I am looking for web option